# How to implement a all-fit full screen mode in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen

By all-fit I mean it should also work when embedded in an `<iframe>` whose size is limited.

Code like below won't work in that case:

```
        main.media.videoWidth = event.stage.stageWidth;
        main.media.videoHeight = event.stage.stageHeight
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)(js library) to manipulate with swf's sizes. You should use something like

```
swfobject.embedSWF(loader, "flashcontent", "100%", "100%", playerMinVersion, null, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

take a closer look at 
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation